# How to access source code of translated page using Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I was trying out different things with Jsoup to see if I could pull information from web pages, when I came across this problem with Google translate. I got far enough so that my program could spit out a url that goes directly to a translated page, but when I try to extract the source code from it, it takes the code from the **Translating...** page. 
Here is an example link of a page in Japanese:

http://translate.google.com/translate_p?sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://mixi.jp/&depth=1&usg=ALkJrhhBn74JodxnRkFSjqBuPEZ2RJRJAQ

(this link changes back to the original Google translate page after a while)

If you open this url and quickly hit ctrl + u, you will get the source code of the Translating page I was talking about earlier (which is what Jsoup does when I extract it from this url). How can I access the source code that comes after this (on the translated page)?

I have already attempted to pull the link from the translated page and follow it, but it does not give me the results I would like. Please only help me access the page page that comes after **Translating...**

**This code spits out a link that takes you past the iframe**

```
    //GET INTO FIRST FRAME OF GOOGLE TRANSLATE PAGE     
    //translate web page from English to English through google translate
    String url1 = "http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://mixi.jp/";

    //create doc to hold html content
    Document document1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0").get();

    //take url1 to web page where actual content is 
    Element link = document1.select("iframe").first();
    String linkSrc1 = link.attr("abs:src");

    System.out.println("linkSrc1: " + linkSrc1);
    //END OF GET INTO FIRST FRAME OF GOOGLE TRANSLATE PAGE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup doesn't load iframe automatically.

*"The page that comes after **Translating...**"* is loaded in an iframe actually.

Here is how you can get it:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://translate.google.com/translate_p?sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://mixi.jp/&depth=1&usg=ALkJrhiYgjK_C-VB2hFQ6iJp08gETWw9yQ").get();

Elements elements = doc.select("iframe[name=c]");
if (elements.size() == 1) {
   Document pageAfterTranslation = Jsoup.connect(elements.first().attr("abs:src")).get();
   // ...
} else {
   throw new RuntimeException("Not exactly ONE iframe found...");
}
```

Comment: Hey Stephan, thanks for the answer, but for some reason the link now takes you to the original google translate page with the iframe. When I posted this question, I had already gotten past that. My mistake for not explaining that better earlier! I have uploaded my code to show how I can spit out the link to a page that passes the iframe. However, the **Translating...** page pops up temporarily when you use the program I wrote and then shows the actual translated page without an iframe.

Comment: @Fluke_of_Luke If you have found a satisfying solution, post it as answer and mark as accepted then

Comment: I haven't though, I'm talking about getting the source code from the link that you get out of the iframe. When trying to access that link, I get the source code of the Translating... page as opposed to the page the comes right after.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the **Translating... ** page does a meta refresh that redirects towards the actual page I want. Would you please take the time to check that out? Thanks!